# Rails 3: Using Simple_form how do I create a form that do a Post to specialities#create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Simple_form how do I create a form that do a Post to specialities#create?

I tried this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @course_group, :html => 
   { :method => 'post', 
     :action=> 'create', 
     :controller=>'specialities' }
```

But the form that is created is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" 
   action="/course_groups" 
   class="simple_form course_group" 
   controller="specialities" 
   id="new_course_group" 
   method="post">
```

What I expected is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" 
   action="/specialities" 
   class="simple_form course_group" 
   controller="specialities" 
   id="new_course_group" 
   method="post">
```

Comment: I added what I tried and what I expected

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using the `:url` option, instead of including `:action` & `:controller` right in the html hash. I would re-write your example as:

```
<%= simple_form_for @course_group, 
    :url => url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'specialities'),
    :method => 'post' do |f| %>
```

Check out the actual `form_for` reference in http://api.rubyonrails.org

Comment: You can substitute the hash with `:url => specialities_path` as long as you setup routes for your `SpecialitiesController` in `routes.rb`: `resources :specialities, only: [:index, :create]`.