# Re-writing Rails form helper in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Is the following line in Rails Simple form

```
<% form_for @user :url => {:action => "attempt_login"},  do |f| %>
```

The same as the following in Rails form helper?

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'attempt_login') do %>
```

If not, can you tell me what it would be? I need to redo some form code and I would like write down the correct syntax before running the app...
For in the case of passing parameters (i.e. :action) the simple form documentation is rather ambiguous.
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to change that (assumedly working) `form_tag` to a `form_for`?

Comment: The best way to see if the output is the same between the two is to run them and compare the output. Not trying to be facetious - that's just the only way to verify what you're trying to confirm.

Comment: My issue is getting my older but working rails form helper code to work properly with the simple form gem...without too much run around. See below...

Comment: Well, now you're talking about something completely different. `form_for` and `simple_form_for` are not the same thing. Your question is comparing `form_for` to `form_tag`.

Comment: Yes, I guess I made a mistake. The first statement in the question should of been. <% simple_form_for @user :url => {:action => "attempt_login"},  do |f| %>

Comment: Well anyway... thanks for trying to help. It appears the following post had what I was looking for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855801/rails-3-using-simple-form-how-do-i-create-a-form-that-do-a-post-to-specialities

Answer (score 2):

The **`form_for`** is *usually* used for a specific record in order to `update` or `create` it.

Example:

```
# view in HAML (not ERB)
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.text_field :username

# matched with the routes
resources :users
```

other example with nested resources:

```
# routes.rb
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end

# view in HAML
= form_for [@user, @post] do |f|
  = f.text_field :content
```

Since you gave a record as an argument to the `form_for` method, it can "pre-fill" some fields of your record, i.e. if the `@user` already has a value for `username`, the field will be populated with that username.

It is true that **you can specify an action** to the `form_for`, something like this:

```
= form_for @user, url: { action: :custom_action } do |f|
```

---

The **`form_tag`** is used for the "*other forms*", such as a `login` form or a specific controller's action to be done.

Example:

```
# view in HAML
- form_tag action: :login do
  = text_field_tag :username
  = password_field_tag :password
```

---

**To conclude**, I would (based on my opinion) use the `form_for` helper if you are actually using a model's instance in the form and trying to modify/create it. So **in your case**, I would not use the `form_for` helper but use the `form_tag` instead (because you want a login form).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help... It appears the following post had what I was looking for  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855801/rails-3-using-simple-form-how-do-i-create-a-form-that-do-a-post-to-specialities

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated my form_tag methods to form_for because form_for was used in a gem that formatted my form using bootstrap.  This was for a login form with no model.  Here's how I used form_for without a model:

```
<%= form_for(:login, :action => 'attempt_login') do %>
```

I assume this works for simple_form as well:

```
<%= simple_form_for(:login, :action => 'attempt_login') do %>
```

Instead of using a `form_tag`, because the gem didn't decorate it, I used a `form_for` with a `:symbol` instead of a `@model`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: But would that work with   <%= f.input :username %>
             <%= f.input :password %>
             <%= f.button :login %>

Comment: Yes: `<%= simple_form_for(:login, :action => 'attempt_login') do |f| %><%=f.input :username %><% end %>`  It was a lot easier for me to do this than to replace all the syntax to prettify the forms.  In the controller though, You will need to update the `param[:username]` to `param[:login][:username]` etc